# How to debug NativeScript with Visual Studio Android Simulator

Tags: visual-studio-code, nativescript

How to debug NativeScript with Visual Studio Android Simulator?
I have the extensions installed and I looked at launch.json but could not find any docs on how to attach my Visual Studio emulator for Android to Visual Code editor?

[image]

thanks,

Sean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most Visual Studio Code extensions that come with a debug configuration, so does the NativeScript extension.

You go to the debug view (the one on the screenshot), and click the cogwheel icon with the little red exclamation mark (means you don't have a default launch configuration), you will be prompted to choose a debug configuration for Node.js, NativeScript Extension, or another language/extension. You simply pick NativeScript and the project will be configured for you with a `launch.json`.

Now you simply need to press the `play` button (green arrow pointing to the right) and you are good to go.

Comment: TX,,, deleted my launch.json and that did the trick, now I need to figure whyI am getting an error of Command failed: Can't connect. Check the application is running on the device... it does launch the app, but I got that error :/

Comment: @born2net what versions of the CLI and `tns-android` are you running?

Comment: nvm it works GREAT after I deleted my launch.json and created a new one per the advice tx again!!!